# Error when trying to install Angular Cli or update current Node.js Version

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I'm new to angular. So in order to learn angular i tried to install it. But it give me the following error

I tried to update my node also. But that also failed.

I used following commands for it......
    npm install npm -g (For npm update)
    npm install -g @angular/cli  (For Angular update)

My current node version is 8, and OS is Win10.

**The Error is**

```
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org 
registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
```

Comment: are you installing it on a corporate pc? could be a proxy issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check your config settings: `npm config list`

Then you could add or change your proxy settings:

```
npm config set http-proxy http://your_proxy_ip:port
npm config set https-proxy http://your_proxy_ip:port
```

Answer is from here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17947

Answer (score -1):

Please refer this site, [besthostadvisor.com/blog/how-to-update-node-js/](https://besthostadvisor.com/blog/how-to-update-node-js/) it includes all methods to update the node

Answer (score -1):

I had that problem with npm 6.0.9 and i did this:
i use npm install -g @angular/cli with the powershell 
and this is functionalling correctly.